# How to store method call and some parameter into $data variable to pass it the view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's I have following code

```
 $loginvalues = $this->user_model->get_all_details(SYSTEM_LOGIN, $condition);
```

I will normally pass it to the **view** as following

```
$this->load->view('site/landing/add_testing_project', $this->data);
```

it will load that function and will grab all details,but additionally I need to add an extra parameter which will be an array as follows

```
 $data['message'] = array("type" => "success");
```

how can i possibly pass it the view?
I tried like following

```
$data['message'] = array("type" => "success");
$data['login_details'] = $this->user_model->get_all_details(SYSTEM_LOGIN, $condition);
```

but it doesn't executing the calling method, my method structure is:

```
 public function get_all_details($table = '', $condition = '') {

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Just add the additional data to the `$this->data` member like `$this->data['message'] = array("type" => "success");` and pass it to the view with `$this->load->view('site/landing/add_testing_project', $this->data);`

Comment: Sorry, I have created like $data instead of $this->data['some']='thing'. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you explain where is issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
I can pass a method call and extra parameter by using following code

```
$this->user_model->get_all_details(SYSTEM_LOGIN, $condition);
        $this->data['message'] = 'success';
```